# Exception "The disk is full " is thrown when trying to store data in usedata object in IE7+

Tags: internet-explorer

I am using userdata object in IE7+ to store client side data. Behind the scenes IE uses xml files to store this data. Also, IE imposes restriction on the max. amount of data that can be stored per file and this limitation is based upon the security zone web url falls in. For a trusted site the allowed size is 128KB. The data that I am storing exceeds this limit and I get "The disk is full" exception. Couple of Q's regarding this:

1) What type of exception does IE throw in this case? I need this info so that I can catch only this exception while ignoring others.
2) What other type of exception userdata.save can throw? I can find any relevant information on the MSDN

Thanks.